# BraintreeWebhookNotification is not working in php

Tags: php, zend-framework2, webhooks, braintree

I have done with the braintree Onboarding sub-merchants.It is working fine for me.After that I am trying to access the status of submerchants by using webhooks. But it is not working.I didn't get any response.Can anyone help me out.I am using zendframework. Please find my below code for reference.

```
use Braintree\Configuration;
use Braintree\ClientToken;
use Braintree\Transaction;
use Braintree\PaymentMethodNonce;
use Application\Model\Transactions;
use Braintree\MerchantAccount;
use Braintree\WebhookNotification;
use Braintree\Result\Error;
$Braintree = new \Braintree\Configuration();

$Braintree::environment($this->config['global_const']['braintree_details']['environment']);

$Braintree::merchantId($this->config['global_const']['braintree_details']['merchantId']);

$Braintree::publicKey($this->config['global_const']['braintree_details']['publicKey']);

$Braintree::privateKey($this->config['global_const']['braintree_details']['privateKey']);

if(isset($_POST["bt_signature"]) && isset($_POST["bt_payload"])) {
$webhookNotification = \Braintree\WebhookNotification::parse($_POST["bt_signature"],   $_POST["bt_payload"]);
$message = $webhookNotification->kind; 
$message .= $webhookNotification->timestamp; 
$this->logger->err('Response:' . "\n" . message);
}
```

Comment: Just confirming, have you [added the destination URL](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/webhooks#creating-webhooks) in your Braintree Control Panel?

Comment: Yes added the url , getting the bt_signature and bt_payload but when its parsed the response is not coming in webhookNotification result .

Comment: thanks. I think you might be missing a `$` next to the variable `message` in your last line of code. Are you seeing the `Response:` text in your results?

Comment: I added $message and checked but still I am not getting any response.
I printed the bt_signature and bt_payload it is coming but the result is not coming

Comment: @Ram I think hollabaq is referring to this line of the snippet that you shared above: `$this->logger->err('Response:' . "\n" . message);`. Try: `$this->logger->err('Response:' . "\n" . $message);`.